# Android: how to set Wifi settings to access Internet connection in Android simulator?

Tags: android

I am working on an Android application which does http request and download contents etc. I want to test such cases on Android Simulator. I am using Android SDK 1.6.
As my computer(Mac OS X) has Internet connectivity via Wifi, i'm trying to activate Wifi connectivity in Android Simulator as well, so that my code can get data connection access to download the data from http server. But when i try to connect it, it says 'Unable to start Wi-Fi' in the simulator wireless settings. If i try to browse in emulator browser, it says 'page not available, check connection etc'. Can you please tell me how to have internet connection on Android Emulator?
I don't know how to set Wifi settings in Android simulator. Could someone help me on this?

System: Mac OS X
Android SDK: 1.6
Editor: Eclipse IDE for Java developers.
Internet connectivity on Mac system: via WiFi

Please give me step by step procedure to have internet connectivity on Android Emulator as i didn't find anything from anywhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The emulator should connect by default to the internet. A 3G icon should be present in the notification bar.

Restart the emulator a couple of times until appears. At least that how works for me on a Windows. Don't forget to add permission to use the Internet in your manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you. It is already showing 3G on top of the emulator screen. but not connecting internet. I didn't add permission in manifest file. How to add it? What is the format?

Comment: It worked perfectly after adding '<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>' in manifest file. Thanks a lot Mr.Pentium10

Answer (score 2):

Try using these Android permissions.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```